# reading and sorting a variable length CSV file

Tags: cobol

We am using OpenVMS system and I believe it is using the [Cobol from HP](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/cobol.html).

With a data file of a lot of records ( 500mb or more ) which **variable length**. The records are comma delimited. I would like to parse each records and extract corresponding fields for processing. After that, I might want to sort it by some particular fields. Is it possible with cobol?

I've seen sorting with fixed-length records only.

Answer (score 2):

Variable length is no problem, not sure exactly how this is done in VMS cobol but the IBMese for this is:-

FILE  SECTION.
 FD  THE-FILE RECORD IS VARYING  DEPENDING ON REC-LENGTH.
 01  THE-RECORD  PICTURE X(5000) .
 WORKING-STORAGE  SECTION.
 01  REC-LENGTH  PICTURE 9(5)  COMPUTATIONAL.

When you read the file "REC-LENGTH" will contain the record length, when write a record  it will write a record of length REC-LENGTH.

To handle the delimited record files you will probably need to use the "UNSTRING" verb to convert into a fixed format. This is pretty verbose (but then this is COBOL).

```
    UNSTRING record DELIMITED BY ","
INTO field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 etc....
END-UNSTRING
```

Once the record is in fixed format you can use the SORT as normal.

Comment: But I've only seen sorting based on fixed format. Do you mean to unstring the variable-length record into distinct fixed length columns?

Answer (score 0):

The Cobol SORT verb will do what you need.

If the SD file contains variable-length records, all of the KEY data-items must be contained within the first n character positions of the record, where n equals the minimum records size
specified for the file.  In other words, they have to be in the fixed part.

However, you can get around this easily by using an input procedure.  This will let you create a virtual file that has its keys in the right place.  In your input procedure, you will reformat your variable, comma delimited, record, into one that has its keys at the front, then "Release" it to the sort.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory is correct, VMS has a SORT/MERGE utility that you could use after you have processed the file into a fixed file format (variable may also be possible). Typically a standalone SORT utility performs better than in-line COLBOL SORT and can be better design if the sort criteria changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a solution in COBOL, at least not to sort the file. The UNIX sort utility should do it just fine, just call sort -t ',' -n with maybe a couple of other options.

Comment: OpenVMS <> UNIX. Try suggesting solutions that fit the question.