# How can we eliminate junk value in field?

Tags: cobol, openvms

I have some csv record which are variable in length , for example:

0005464560,45667759,ZAMTR,!To ACC 12345678,DR,79.85

0006786565,34567899,ZAMTR,!To ACC 26575443,DR,1000

I need to seperate each of these fields and I need the last field which should be a money.

However, as I read the file, and unstring the record into fields, I found that the last field contain junk value at the end of itself. The amount(money) field should be 8 characters, 5 digit at the front, 1 dot, 2 digit at the end. The values from the input could be any value such as 13.5, 1000 and 354.23 .

```
    "FILE SECTION"

        FD INPUT_FILE.
            01 INPUT_REC                                   PIC X(66).

    "WORKING STORAGE SECTion"

            01 WS_INPUT_REC                                 PIC X(66).

            01 WS_AMOUNT_NUM                                PIC 9(5).9(2).
            01 WS_AMOUNT_TXT                                PIC X(8).

"MAIN SECTION"

                        UNSTRING INPUT_REC DELIMITED BY ","
                        INTO WS_ID_1, WS_ID_2, WS_CODE, WS_DESCRIPTION, WS_FLAG, WS_AMOUNT_TXT

                        MOVE WS_AMOUNT_TXT(1:8) TO WS_AMOUNT_NUM(1:8)

                        DISPLAY WS_AMOUNT_NUM
```

From the display, the value is rather normal: 345.23, 1000, just as what are, however, after I wrote the field into a file, here is what they become:

79.85^M^@^@
137.35^M^@

I have inspect the field WS_AMOUNT_NUM, which came from the field WS_AMOUNT_TXT, and found that ^@ is a kind of LOW-VALUE. However, I cannot find what is ^M, it is not a space, not a high-value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing, but it looks like you may be reading variable length records from a file into a fixed length 
COBOL record. The junk
at the end of the COBOL record is giving you some grief. Hard to say how consistent that junk is going
to be from one read to the next (data beyond the bounds of actual input record length are technically
undefined). That junk ends up 
being included in `WS_AMOUNT_TXT` after the `UNSTRING`

There are a number of ways to solve this problem. The suggestion I am giving you here may not
be optimal, but it is simple and should get the job done.

The last `INTO` field, `WS_AMOUNT_TXT`, in your `UNSTRING` statement is the one that receives all of the trailing
junk. That junk needs to be stripped off. Knowing that the only valid characters in the last field are
digits and the decimal character, you could clean it up as follows:

```
PERFORM VARYING WS_I FROM LENGTH OF WS_AMOUNT_TXT BY -1
          UNTIL WS_I = ZERO
    IF WS_AMOUNT_TXT(WS_I:1) IS NUMERIC OR
       WS_AMOUNT_TXT(WS_I:1) = '.'
       MOVE ZERO TO WS_I
    ELSE
       MOVE SPACE TO WS_AMOUNT_TXT(WS_I:1)
    END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

The basic idea in the above code is to scan from the end of the last `UNSTRING` output field
to the beginning replacing anything that is not a valid digit or decimal point with a space.
Once a valid digit/decimal is found, exit the loop on the assumption that the rest will
be valid.

After cleanup use the intrinsic function `NUMVAL` as outlined in my answer to [your
previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839570/how-can-i-convert-an-alphanumeric-and-use-it-for-calculation/6846590#6846590)
to convert WS_AMOUNT_TXT into a numeric data type.

One final piece of advice, `MOVE SPACES TO INPUT_REC` before each `READ` to blow away data left over
from a previous read that might be left in the buffer. This will protect you when reading a very "short"
record after a "long" one - otherwise you may trip over data left over from the previous read.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** Just noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488443/reading-and-sorting-a-variable-length-csv-file/6489453#6489453) to your question about reading variable length files. Using a variable length input record is a better approach. Given the
actual input record length you can do something like:

```
UNSTRING INPUT_REC(1:REC_LEN) INTO...
```

Where `REC_LEN` is the variable specified after `OCCURS DEPENDING ON` for the `INPUT_REC` file `FD`. All the junk you are encountering occurs after the end of the record as defined by `REC_LEN`. Using reference modification as illustrated above trims it off before `UNSTRING` does its work to separate out the individual data fields.

**EDIT 2:**
*Cannot use reference modification with `UNSTRING`*. Darn... It is possible with some other COBOL dialects but not with OpenVMS COBOL. Try the following:

```
MOVE INPUT_REC(1:REC_LEN) TO WS_BUFFER
UNSTRING WS_BUFFER INTO...
```

Where `WS_BUFFER` is a working storage `PIC X` variable long enough to hold the longest input record. When you `MOVE` a short alpha-numeric field to a longer one, the destination field is left justified with spaces used to pad remaining space (ie. `WS_BUFFER`). Since leading and trailing spaces are acceptable to the `NUMVAL` fucnction you have exactly what you need.

I have a reason for pushing you in this direction. Any junk that ends up at the trailing end of a record buffer when reading a short record is undefined. There is a possibility that some of that junk just might end up being a digit or a decimal point. Should this occur, the cleanup routine I originally suggested would fail.

**EDIT 3:**
*There are no ^@ in the resulting WS_AMOUNT_TXT, but still there are a ^M*

Looks like the file system is treating <CR> (that ^M thing) at the end of each record as data.

If the file you are reading came from a Windows platform and you are now
reading it on a UNIX platform that would explain the problem. Under Windows records
are terminated with <CR><LF> while on UNIX they are terminated with <LF> only. The
UNIX file system treats <CR> as if it were part of the record.

If this is the case, you can be pretty sure that there will be a single <CR> at the
end of every record read. There are a number of ways to deal with this:

**Method 1:** As you already noted, pre-edit the file using Notepad++ or some other
tool to remove the <CR> characters before processing through your COBOL program.
Personally I don't think this is the best way of going about it. I prefer to use a COBOL
only solution since it involves fewer processing steps.

**Method 2:** Trim the last character from each input record before processing it. The last
character should always be <CR>. Try the following if you
are reading records as variable length and have the actual input record length available.

```
SUBTRACT 1 FROM REC_LEN
MOVE INPUT_REC(1:REC_LEN) TO WS_BUFFER
UNSTRING WS_BUFFER INTO...
```

**Method 3:** Treat <CR> as a delimiter when UNSTRINGing as follows:

```
UNSTRING INPUT_REC DELIMITED BY "," OR x"0D"
    INTO WS_ID_1, WS_ID_2, WS_CODE, WS_DESCRIPTION, WS_FLAG, WS_AMOUNT_TXT
```

**Method 4:** Condition the last receiving field from UNSTRING by replacing trailing
non digit/non decimal point characters with spaces. I outlined this solution a litte earlier in this
question. You could also explore the `INSPECT` statement using the `REPLACING` option (Format 2). This should be able to do pretty much the same thing - just replace all x"00" by SPACE and x"0D" by SPACE.

Where there is a will, there is a way. Any of the above solutions should work for you. Choose the one you are most comfortable with.

Comment: I tried the variable length INPUT_REC for UNSTRING, it said we cannot use reference mod in UNSTRING...

Comment: I used Notepad++ to convert the file to unix format line end (LF only), and the ^M is gone. I am wondering if I can accecpt this approach. There maybe some file generate by windows too. Just I think.

Comment: i managed to loop through the whole string and look for a character X"0D" which seems to define CR and it works with file generated by Windows. Do you think it is good approach?

Comment: @gunbuster363. Check out EDIT 3.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really. You are so nice. The answer deserve more votes IMHO. In addition, do you know why CR can be recognized by using X"0D"? Do we have a list of such representation of special characters?

Comment: @gunbuster363. Have a look at this [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/). Notice that <CR> corresponds to x"0D". Every 8 bit pattern can be described in terms of two hex digits, which in turn corresponds to something on the chart. Some of the patterns are not printable and have special meanings to the particular OS and file system you are using. Typically some combination of <CR>, <LF> are used to indicate ends of lines or records in ASCII based systems (eg. UNIX, Windows, Apple)

Answer (score 0):

^M is a carriage return.

Would [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) be useful for rectifying this data?

Comment: the website you provided is 404. Sorry.

Comment: Apologies, fixed link, didn't verify before posting and the StackOverflow link UI confused me a little

Comment: Hmmmm...actually I think the messy data is generated by the program, but I am wondering why. I believe the input data is clean.